# Replace Icons with Images in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, imageicon

I am trying to create a beautiful box on html/css which is like that :

[image]

And I am trying to change the icons to look like :

[image]

Here is the original code :

```
#pricing-table .pricing .pricing-list ul li i {
  margin-right: 12px;
  color: #bdc3c7;
}
```

And by applying this change it does not work :

```
#pricing-table .pricing .pricing-list ul li i {
  margin-right: 12px;
  background-image: url("./Startup Framework Inspired Pricing Table_files/images/background.jpeg");
}
```

I tried this one and it is working but is it the optimal way?

```
<li>
  <img id="icons" src="./Startup Framework Inspired Pricing Table_files/images/icon.jpg">
  <span> +/- % </span> MTD
</li>
```

Comment: Unless you can demo this it's hard to help. Does the `i` have any dimensions when you inspect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u use `background-image` you must specify some width and height for the element